# how to validate a response Angular function?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular scopes and other stuff. Curently working on a system with authentication.

```
$scope.logUserIn = function(){
      $http.post('api/user/login', $scope.login).success(function(response){

        localStorage.setItem('User-Data', JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.loggedIn=true;

      }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

So, want to validate **response** because if i put some fake e-mail or a password response by the server pending .....forever. 
Error function does not fires when i put some fake creditials.

Comment: Just. Do it! What is your problem? If you want to validate it - do it. Not sure, that you need to validate it on client, don't you? I think, you think to do it on server (`api/user/login`). Do it and return some response with error code, like 401. `error` function will be fired.

Comment: validating the response is not the frontend job. you should validate the input prior to sending it, and the server should validate it when receiving it and send the status and error accordingly... you should not have to verify items in the frontend... if you want you can simulate a timeout method that runs but again... server side validations should be preformed there